# Can I suspend or resume a route based on a condition?

Tags: apache-camel

I want to be able to control programmatically a Route based on a condition but I cannot find a way to do it. 
I don't want to stop the flow of a Route as in `ProcessorDefinition.stop()`.
I tried to create a new `RoutePolicy` without any luck.

```
public class ProjectStateRoutePolicy extends RoutePolicySupport {

    // this would be a check to an outside service
    private boolean shouldStartRoute = false;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Route route) {
        suspendIfNotInValidState(route);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(Route route) {
        suspendIfNotInValidState(route);
    }

    private void suspendIfNotInValidState(Route route) {
        if ( !shouldStartRoute) {
            try {
                suspendRoute(route);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 throw ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to my understanding `onResume()` and the like are CamelContext specific and not Route specific. Is there a fine-grained mechanism in place to have knowledge of a Route Lifecycle?

I want to be a able to control the lifecycle of the Route even if somene tries to start the Route manually e.g.from JMX.

PS: I don't think that Events such as RouteStartedEvent satisfy this constraint, since messages may have been consumed in between receiving and acting upon the event.

Comment: Hmmm maybe [ControlBus](http://camel.apache.org/controlbus) component might be useful in such a scenario. Is this correct?

Comment: Controlbus is only available in the more recent versions of camel - we wanted to use it but when we were using 2.10 there was no luck :(

Comment: The other way to "suspend" a route is of course to just encode a bean into the route with a boolean flag which you can turn on/off.

Comment: @vikingsteve By "suspending" you are referring to `from(someEndpoint).stop()` I presume. I could do this, but it is a dirty hack. 
I 'd like to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Actually, no, using `.stop()` won't stop the route from processing, it just bails out at that point. I have some code I can dig out tomorrow, if that would help? I hear `controlbus` apparently is quite good for this, even if I haven't used it.

Comment: I agree. That's why I was said using `stop()` is a dirty hack in my case. In any case, I would be more than grateful for a code sample. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that can do it, given you have the camel context and the route name.

```
public class StopRoute {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    public void stop(CamelContext camelContext, String routeId) throws Exception {
        log.info("Stopping camel route: " + routeId);
        camelContext.stopRoute(routeId, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Similarly for StartRoute.

And then you can use it in your route like this:

```
    .bean(StopRoute.class, "stop(*, " + INCOMING_SNAPSHOTS.routeId() + ")")
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. `controlbus:` essentially would do the same thing, as I understand ;)

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you just need to use a bean which holds the state, and disable/enable processing within the route based on that.

Comment: Thnx. But that is not what I wanted. What I want is to a way to suspend and resume a route in 'automatically' according to a condition out of the scope of the route, e.g according to the status of the service (started, stopped, live, pre-live...). I hope this clarifies a bit, what I 'm looking for.

A RoutePolicy can help towards this, but it lacks a RouteSuspendedEvent or a RouteResumedEvent. There are only RouteStartedEvent and RouteStoppedEvent events emmited.

Comment: Yeap. But I wanted an elegant way to suspend or resume  the route and not just to disable/enable processing within the route.

Comment: How about `camelContext.suspendRoute(routeId, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` ? Your bean only needs to know the CamelContext.

Comment: I want something like that but I think I need to do it in another thread since, the route I want to suspend/resume is the same that calls it. I will look into it later. Thanks for your help in any case.

Comment: No problem to do it in another thread, just make sure that thread knows the camel context... good luck.